# What does the "Point?" stand for?

Tags: c#

I have a quick question:

While looking for a way to paint over picture boxes I found acode that helped me, but I'm confused by this bit:

```
private Point? _previous = null;
```

What does the "?" stand for? And why there is "_" before the name, is it because "previous" is already used as a name by basic commands?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: It means `Nullable`. It is equavalent to `Nullable<Point>`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know what to put in google to search for this :)

Comment: And the underscore is just a convention... it doesn't _have_ to be there. Some people use it for private variables, especially when there's a public property with a getter/setter that uses that private variable.